# WebStorm - JS - Wrapping and Braces - unpack a property

Tags: javascript, format, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I don't know what is the proper name of this thing so let me show you what I want.

The problem is in this part of code:

[image]

I want it to be like this:

[image]

But I can't find the settings for this part of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to disable:

Function Declaration Parameters->Align when multiline